How to search table for special characters excluding some Hungarian letters?
I want to return all rows containing any other character than letters, numbers and space, but I also want to whitelist Hungarian letters. However when I run the following script:
SELECT
    *
FROM
    table T
WHERE
    T.columnname REGEXP '[^a-zA-Z0-9 áéíóöőúüű]';

It gives this error:

SQL Error (1267): Illegal mix of collations (latin1_swedish_ci,IMPLICIT) and (utf8mb4_general_ci,COERCIBLE) for operation 'regexp'

What's the correct way to do this?

If you want to match specific Unicode letters, you may probably replace them with \x{XXXX} notation. If you just mean any letter, digit and space, you may probably just use T.columnname REGEXP '[^\\p{L}\\d ]'

letters - according to what language? Hungarian?

I specifically want these letters ignored, not all letters (as well as not all spaces).

Does that mean a to z are letters, and other letters are special characters?

please show output of show create table yourtablename and show variables like '%collation%'

Use an Unicode collation and sleep well at night. The concept of "special characters" is a remnant from the 90s that is fully resolved now.

Which way are things?

Table (and column) are latin1 but `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE char%' indicates "utf8" (or utf8mb4)?

There is a mess because of "Mojibake".  Each accented letter was stored as two "latin1" bytes.

Vice versa.
WHERE T.columnname REGEXP '[^a-zA-Z0-9 áéíóöőúüű]' CHARACTER SET utf8


Before pursuing the problem further, please provide
SHOW CREATE TABLE T;
SELECT HEX(columnname) FROM T ...;  -- (for a sample)

What will you do with the rows that are returned?  This may impact the answer.
As of about a decade ago "latin1" is the wrong way to store accented letters.  So, I will also recommend converting the dataset to utf8mb4.
What version of MySQL are you running?  (This impacts whether utf8mb4 is available and whether regexp can handle things like what is in the Comments.)

Cannot agree more. I moved to Unicode and life is so much easier.
